# Select statement with default values

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I have have a statement like the one below, is there a way to select all values from tableA including those that don't connect to tableB (with b.value being NULL or empty)? Thanks for any help.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.value, b.value 
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON ....
```

Comment: What you want is the default behavior of a LEFT join. You will get all the rows of tableA.

Comment: Even if I specifically select a value from b? If that's so, than I'm dumb and my problem is elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: No, if you *specifically select a value from b* in a WHERE clause then you have an INNER join. Put the condition in the ON clause instead of WHERE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you described is exactly what a `left join` would do. There's nothing extra you need to do (except for completing the join condition you left out, of course).